# Worklight JSONStore or SQLite to store password?

Tags: sqlite, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I want to store passwords in a database in a Worklight application. What is the difference of JSONStore and SQLite as both can be used to store data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONStore provides encryption for all the data stored inside, just use [usePassword](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_usepassword.html) before calling [initCollection](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_initcollection.html). Make sure the password used to decrypt/access the contents of JSONStore is not hardcoded. Ideally just prompt the user for a password and if they fail to login a couple of times destroy the contents of JSONStore with [destroy](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_destroy.html). SQLite out of the box won't allow you to encrypt all the data stored, JSONStore will.

Comment: You're going to have a bit of a bootstrapping problem as you need a way to get the password to open JSONStore, in order to get the user/passwords you app stored.

Comment: On a related matter, is there a way to ask JSONStore to encrypt data using a particular algorithm? For example I want to specify that encryption is done using TwoFish or AES.

Comment: @MinhPham: Not currently, you can submit a feature request [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=461545&tstart=0). Right now it's a 256bit [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) key derived from the user's password using [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2).

Answer (score 1):

Since what you are storing is username password you should encrypt them.
In Worklight it is easier to do that in JSONStore then in SQLite.